# PyCharm git commit split code block change

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, git-commit

Is there a way in PyCharm/IntelliJ to split a block of code-changes into multiple parts, so I can commit only parts of it and if so, how?

I.e. in the example I can only tick the checkbox on line 222 and get the entire code-block in my changeset. What I'd like is to only add line 223 to the commit, but not line 224.

[image]

Comment: Easy in command-line Git, `git add -p`. I gather you don't want a command line Git answer though, so let's take out the [tag:git] tag.

Comment: Currently, it's not possible to commit only a single line within IDE, please feel free to vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186988

Answer (score 1):

The 2023.2 update of PyCharm introduces this feature (I'm running build #PY-232.8660.197, built on July 26, 2023).

You should be able to include only specific lines within a codeblock from now on:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> 2021: Currently, it's not possible to commit only a single line within IDE,

Actually, the 2018 [issue IDEA-186988](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186988) just got an early implementation (June 2023)

[Dmitriy Smirnov](https://twitter.com/dvsmir) (Product Manager, VCS at JetBrains) adds:

> initial implementation of the feature is available in the EAP5 build 232.7754.73, released today.
> It allows splitting chunk into several lines and select them individually.
>
> Please try it out and let us know if there are any issues.

This is in progress, with multiple related issues (like [IDEA-322590](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-322590/Commit-specific-lines-checkboxes-state-in-split-chunk-are-not-remembered-after-Undo)).

It is now (Q2 2023) available with 2023.2.

[image: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/api/files/74-1880164?sign=MTY5MjMxNjgwMDAwMHwxMS0xOTkwNzJ8NzQtMTg4MDE2NHxzeFoweVpZamJTV2Z3MkI0MUN3UnRN%0D%0AODNVb1VyQS1BNWVtNHVNenJWMU84DQo%0D%0A&updated=1690707045800]

Answer (score -1):

In PyCharm, when making a commit in Git, you have the ability to select and stage specific changes within a code block. This feature is called "Splitting a Change" or "Partial Commit." Here's how you can use it:

1. Open the version control tool window: Go to the bottom right of the PyCharm window and click on the Git icon or navigate to "View" → "Tool Windows" → "Version Control" to open the version control tool window.
2. Review the changes: In the version control tool window, you'll see a list of files with changes. Expand the file that contains the code block you want to split. You should be able to see the changes made within that file.
3. Select the code block to split: In the file diff view, locate the specific code block you want to include in the commit. You can click and drag your mouse to select the desired lines or use the keyboard shortcuts to make the selection (e.g., Shift + Arrow keys).[read more][1]
4. Right-click and choose "Git" → "Add to VCS" or use the keyboard shortcut: After selecting the desired code block, right-click on the selection and choose "Git" → "Add to VCS." This action stages the selected changes for the commit.
5. Commit the changes: Once the desired changes are staged, you can proceed with the commit. In the version control tool window, you should see the staged changes under the "Default" changelist. Enter a commit message to describe the changes and click on the commit button (usually represented by a green checkmark).

By using the "Splitting a Change" feature, you can selectively commit specific code block changes, separating them from the rest of the modifications made within the file. This can be helpful when you want to keep your commits focused, organized, and more granular.

Note that the exact steps may vary slightly depending on the PyCharm version and your specific configuration.