# How to manually edit current hunk in PyCharm to commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

If i write a command `git add -p` I can manually edit the current and commit only the line I want:

[image]

But in PyCharm I do not know how to do this. I cannot separate each line, PyCharm selects both lines and does not allow me to select one:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this in PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regrettably, there is no option to commit single linges in PyCharm.

There is a feature request for that, please feel free to vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186988/Allow-commiting-only-specific-lines

UPDATE:

Please see comment from @VonC

Indeed, VCS team is working on implementation of a ticket that is mentioned above

Comment: This issue is starting (June 2023) to evolve. See "[PyCharm git commit split code block change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76491897/6309)".